# RecyclerView notifyDataSetChanged() not working - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

`RecyclerView` not update after calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` and I found the problem but not solution.
Here is my code of changing the data.

```
fun changeData(data: List<AccountLite>) {
    // checking the size of the list before
    logI("accountLiteList.size before: " + accountLiteList.size)
    accountLiteList = data.toMutableList()

    // checking the size of the list after
    logI("accountLiteList.size after: " + accountLiteList.size)

    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

But `getItemCount()` still return 0.

Here is the code of `getItemCount()`.

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    logI("getItemCount: " + accountLiteList.size)
    return accountLiteList.size
}
```

And here is the log

```
AccountsRecyclerAdaptor: accountLiteList.size before: 0
AccountsRecyclerAdaptor: accountLiteList.size after: 19
AccountsRecyclerAdaptor: getItemCount: 0
AccountsRecyclerAdaptor: getItemCount: 0
...
```

Why the `getItemCount()` return 0, and the `accountLiteList` not changed anywhere.
[Here](https://gist.github.com/ArbazMateen/9f9d17cd501f11a2504d7e77df0e9c22) is the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `notifyItemChanged(position);` because you're adding items:

```
Int count=0;
for (item: AccountLite in data) 
{
   accountLiteList.add(item);
   notifyItemChanged(count);
   count++;
}
```

Comment: @Ascorbin I had the same problem and I usually avoid it if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to call API using AsyncTask. After lot of tries, I found one solution which worked, but don't know why.

I just added the `inner` keyword to the Async class, and it worked.

Example:

```
inner class ApiCall : AsyncTask
```